# Sharepoint Site permission issue

Tags: 2010, permissions, user-profile, site-collection, recycle-bin

We have a web application based on SharePoint. Every Saturday night Site collection permission default groups gets deleted automatically and it is difficult to find the cause of this issue. We have restored the last working backup but its happening every weekend.

There is no change deployed to server and we are facing this issue from the last two weekends only.

Please suggest how to resolve this issue or any workaround for this.

Comment: Hi Ajit. 
You mention that "there is no change deployed to the server" but you tag the question with "sharepoint-online". Could you please verify if this is SharePoint Online or on premise, and if this is on premise which version are you using. is this on one Site Collection on the web application or everyone?

Comment: its funny that its happning every sat night! so that means there is some timer job that is executed weekly at sat that might be the culprit! has anyone added in any timerjob? can you show the event log (uls log)? it should state what timer job was exectued at what time which should narrow it down.

Comment: Hi Funi, It's in on premise and and we are using sharepoint 2010.

Comment: Have you got any custom solutions installed?

Comment: As Ali Sharepoint pointed out, this is probably something that a timerjob is executing as this is happening at a regular interval. Narrow down the time with event viewer/ULS logs and you will most likely find your culprit. If you have more than one admin working on the box then I would check the scheduled task jobs. Sometimes a badly thought out PowerShell job is configured there and messes everything up.

Comment: Hi Paul, We havn't deployed any custom solution.

Comment: could you please check the ULS logs from all servers during the time frame groups disappear. Do you have any custom security stuff in your farms which run every sat....also check from central admin what is User Profile Sync schedule is......and from central admin time job history check which timer jobs run at that time.

Comment: Thanks people for help! finally the issue is resolved. One of the timer job i.e. Recycle bin is causing this issue.

Comment: I'm guessing that it's a timer job (Recycling Bin?).

Comment: What about use of third party products such as ControlPoint or AvePoint?  It's possible to configure these to run jobs on a scheduled basis to enforce variance governance tasks.

Comment: If this issue is solved you should enter an explanation of the resolution as an answer and accept it so people who encounter the same issue in the future can take advantage of your discovery.

Answer (score 1):

As the issue is reoccurring on a weekly basis it surely points out to a fault Timer Job. Please narrow down your ULS log and you'll find out the culprit. I read in a blog which I'll refer once I find the URL, there are couple of Jobs which can do this and out of them one is "Recycling Bin". You should surely set it to stop on Friday and see the result on Monday. 
I'll update the URL of the blog but you should surely share your results by disabling this particular Timer Job.